# Why am I getting `this.props.onAdd is not a function`?

Tags: reactjs, function

I'm creating a simple CRUD React app that let's you manage products. Products only have a `name` and a `price`.

In my AddProduct component, my `onSubmit` method can successfully log `this.nameInput.value, this.priceInput.value`, but when I change the log to `this.props.onAdd` I get `this.props.onAdd is not a function`.

I'm following a [tutorial](https://youtu.be/S66rHpyU-Eg?t=2948), so I'm sure I'm missing one small thing, but could use another set of eyes on my code.

Here's my `addProduct` component - the `onSubmit` method has the `this.props.onadd(...)`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class AddProduct extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  onSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    this.props.onAdd(this.nameInput.value, this.priceInput.value);
  }
  render() {
    return (
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
            <h3>Add Product</h3>
            <input placeholder="Name" ref={nameInput => this.nameInput = nameInput}/>
            <input placeholder="Price" ref={priceInput => this.priceInput = priceInput}/>
            <button>Add</button>
            <hr />
        </form>
    );
  }
}
```

And here's my App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import ProductItem from './ProductItem';
import AddProduct from './AddProduct';


const products = [
  {
    name: 'iPad',
    price: 200
  },
  {
    name: 'iPhone',
    price: 500
  }
];

localStorage.setItem('products', JSON.stringify(products));


class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      products: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('products'))
    };

    this.onAdd = this.onAdd.bind(this);
    this.onDelete = this.onDelete.bind(this);
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    const products = this.getProducts();
    this.setState({ products });
  }

  getProducts() {
    return this.state.products;
  }

  onAdd(name, price) {
    const products = this.getProducts();

    products.push({
      name,
      price
    });

    this.setState({ products })
  }

  onDelete(name) {
    const products = this.getProducts();

    const filteredProducts = products.filter(product => {
      return product.name !== name;
    });

    this.setState({ products: filteredProducts });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Products Manager</h1>

        <AddProduct

        />

        {
          this.state.products.map(product => {
            return (
             <ProductItem
                key={product.name}
                {...product}
                onDelete={this.onDelete}
              />
            );
          })
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

What's the matter with my code? When I click the Add button, I get the error.

Comment: ` <AddProduct onAdd={onAdd} />` - but you need bind this or use arrow syntax

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because you pass no prop to the `<AddProduct />` you render.

You should add it like so:

```
<AddProduct onAdd={this.onAdd}/>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass the props to the component:

```
<AddProduct onAdd={onAdd}  />
```

Answer (score 2):

Just change the following line

`<form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>`

to

`<form onSubmit={this.onSubmit.bind(this)}>`

Answer (score 0):

`onAdd` is a field in the props of `AddProduct`. It means you should delivery a function to `AddProduct` in `App`. like: `<AddProduct onAdd={() => console.log('works')} />`